# How to pass variable as argument in shell scripting using subprocess (python)?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to call a shell script form Python and need to pass parameters.

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split('./trackTZRun.sh A B'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess 

A = "Hello"
B = "World"

output = subprocess.call(['./trackTZRun.sh', str(A), str(B)],   shell=True)
print output
```

Comment: While this solves OP problem, it would be great if you provided some description and maybe a link to the docs.